# Elisp: Searching for a string with an unbalanced quote causes Lisp error

Tags: regex, elisp

search for `filename . "myfile.txt"`

```
(regexp-quote "filename \. \"\\(.+\\)\"")
"filename \\. \"\\\\(\\.\\+\\\\)\""
```

search for `filename . "myfile.txt` (without last quote)

```
(regexp-quote "filename \. \"\\(.+\\)")
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (invalid-read-syntax ") or . in a vector")
  read(#<buffer processing-files.el>)
  preceding-sexp()
  eval-last-sexp-1(t)
  eval-last-sexp(t)
  eval-print-last-sexp()
  call-interactively(eval-print-last-sexp nil nil)
```

Comment: Here is another simple failing example

<pre>
    (re-search-forward "\"" (point-max) t)

    Debugger entered--Lisp error: (scan-error "Unbalanced        parentheses" 2308 1)
     scan-sexps(2309 -1)
     forward-sexp(-1)
     preceding-sexp()
     eval-last-sexp-1(nil)
     eval-last-sexp(nil)
     call-interactively(eval-last-sexp nil nil)
</pre>

I am using
GNU Emacs 24.0.50.1 (i386-mingw-nt6.1.7600) of 2010-08-04 on
LENNART-69DE564
Windows 7 Ultimate

Comment: I don't get this problem when emacs is loaded without my personal configuration files

Comment: Just comment out different parts of your config files until you narrow it down.

Comment: Uh, what is the question?

Just running those two snippets works fine, so more info is needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you misunderstood what regexp-quote mean:

From the doc (C-h C-f regexp-quote RET)

Return a regexp string which matches exactly string and nothing else.

Or I misunderstood your question.

Anyway if you want to search there is some function search-backward-regexp, search-forward-regexp